# How to upload a file and move to a directory in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am developing a website, i want to upload a file and i want to save the uploaded file to a directory.can anyone please help me to sort this problem out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `SaveAs` method.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried already by searching in net. but during file upload, the content length of the file showing -2 as value.

Comment: the content length of the uploading file is not calculating.and it shows file doesn't exist as exception during uploading...

Comment: Did you select a file in the browser?

Comment: Yes i did select a file in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for that.

It is very easy to use and highly customizeable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i want do it in c#.

Comment: @Arun I understand. Just wanted to let you know there are other options out there.